# Create Azure NSG with C#

Tags: c#, azure, networking

I'm investigating all the ways to automate creating NSG rules in Azure.  I can create them using Powershell, Template, and REST api.  Is it possible to create an NSG rule using just C#? When I google this, absolutely nothing comes up for straight C#.

Comment: "good idea or not?" - Opinion-solicitation questions such as these are off-topic. Have you looked at the Azure SDK for .net, which includes networking?

Comment: I'll take a look at the Azure SDK for .net.  And I'll edit my question. Thanks.

Comment: You can also add Perl, PHP, Python, Node.js (JavaScript), Java and Go as more methods with SDKs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from this site: https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net

```
        string AuthFile = "path to authorization file";
        var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(AuthFile);

        var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Configure().WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic).Authenticate(credentials).WithDefaultSubscription();

        string frontEndNSGName = "testnsg";
        string rgName = "MyResourceGroup";

        var frontEndNSG = azure.NetworkSecurityGroups.Define(frontEndNSGName)
            .WithRegion(Region.USEast)
            .WithExistingResourceGroup(rgName)
            .DefineRule("ALLOW-SSH")
                .AllowInbound()
                .FromAnyAddress()
                .FromAnyPort()
                .ToAnyAddress()
                .ToPort(22)
                .WithProtocol(SecurityRuleProtocol.Tcp)
                .WithPriority(100)
                .WithDescription("Allow SSH")
                .Attach()
            .DefineRule("ALLOW-HTTP")
                .AllowInbound()
                .FromAnyAddress()
                .FromAnyPort()
                .ToAnyAddress()
                .ToPort(80)
                .WithProtocol(SecurityRuleProtocol.Tcp)
                .WithPriority(101)
                .WithDescription("Allow HTTP")
                .Attach()
            .Create();
```